# What does this UPDATE query do?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, database

I am  a litle rusty with DB managment and I have to do some operations on a DB. I have some doubts about what exactly the following MySql query does:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads','www.domain.com/images');
```

I think that it update thes content of the **post_content** column of the **wp_post** table (is it right?).

But I am not sure about what the REPLACE function does, and ultimately what is the exact behavior of the whole query?

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's updating the value of `post_content` in all rows in the table.

If the `post_content` column contains the text `www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads`, then it is replaced with `www.domain.com/images`.

If `post_content` **doesn't** contain that text, then no action is taken on that row.

If, for example, it contains:

`http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/blah/blah/blah.jpg`

then it will become:

`http://www.domain.com/images/blah/blah/blah.jpg`

Comment: *If post_content doesn't contain that text, then no action is taken on that row.* is not technically true, but would only have a noticeable effect if there's a trigger on the table.